# How to execute 'nohup' command through JAVA

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I need to execute 15 to 20 java programs parallely in the background. We can use `nohup`   command and execute it directly but I want to execute this `nohup` command from another `java` program. I did some research on it and created a `java` program. but this below `java` program is working when I use `java` command, but if I use `nohup` then its failing

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sourceFileName = args[0];
    String targetFileName = args[1];
    String type = args[2];
    String logFileName = args[3];
    Integer count = new Integer(args[4]);
    // Below command is working
    String command = "java -cp \"test-jar.jar\" com.test.MyTestClass ";
    // Below command is not working
    // String command = "nohup java -cp \"test-jar.jar\" com.test.MyTestClass ";
    for(int i=1; i<=count; i++){
        String cmd = command+sourceFileName+"_"+i+" "+targetFileName+"_"+i+" "+type+" 2>>"+logFileName+"_"+i+".log &";
        runProcess(cmd);
    }
}
private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    pro.waitFor();
    System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
}
```

For testing purpose I have taken the count as 3, If I use `nohup` command getting below output

```
nohup java -cp "test-jar.jar" com.test.MyTestClass source-file_1 target-file_1 TEST 2>>log-file_1.log & exitValue() 1
nohup java -cp "test-jar.jar" com.test.MyTestClass source-file_2 target-file_2 TEST 2>>log-file_2.log & exitValue() 1
nohup java -cp "test-jar.jar" com.test.MyTestClass source-file_3 target-file_3 TEST 2>>log-file_3.log & exitValue() 1
```

I kept the `test-jar.jar` in the same path from where I am executing this program.

Comment: What's the error when it fails?

Comment: Updated question with the output

Comment: Everything looks OK. You should try to find out what's the error when running each command. In order to do that, instead of printing `pro.exitValue()` you should try to read the contents of `pro.getErrorStream()` and put it in a string and write it to your console. It contains the actual error messages for the command.

Comment: Used `pro.getErrorStream()`  then I got below error `java.lang.Process$PipeInputStream@7cf10a6f`

Comment: The `pro.getErrorStream()` is a stream, you can't just print it's value. What you got is the result of `toString()` method of that stream object. You should read the contents of that stream and convert it to String and then print it. Here are some examples: http://roufid.com/5-ways-convert-inputstream-string-java/

Comment: You need `String command = "/bin/sh nohup java ...";`. `nohup` isn't an executable file, it is a shell command. You should also look into providing a manifest with a `Main-Class` entry and using `java -jar` instead of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of 2 separate projects.
My class is in `my-test` project and the class which I want to execute is in `test-jar` project. I added `test-jar` dependency in 'my-test' project. Still faced the same issue. I added/copied My class in the `test-jar` file then I executed it. Now its working for both `java` and `nohup` commands